# R draw lines over two different scales

Tags: r

I have built two graphs in one (two different y axis but plotting on the same graph). I want to show the connection between the values on the left and the values on the right (Do they stay consistently > 0 or <0 or change?)

Now what I need is to link the two sides of the graph with a line to see if it decreases/increases. So I want a corresponding dot on the left to be linked to the corresponding dot on the right by a line.

But because the y axis values on the left and the right are different, I am not figuring out how this can work.
Here is my code to build the graph:

```
## Plot first set of data and draw its axis
plot(rep(1, length(DEG)), DEG, xlim = c(0,4), xaxt = "n",
    ylim = c(-5, 5), col = "black", xlab = "", ylab = "")
axis(1, at = c(1))

## Allow a second plot on the same graph
par(new = TRUE)

## Plot the second plot and put axis scale on right
plot(rep(3, length(DMG)), DMG, axes = F, xlim = c(0, 4), xaxt = "n", 
    ylim = c(-80, 80), col = "black", xlab = "", ylab = "")
axis(1, at = c(3)))
axis(side = 4)
abline(h = 0, col = "red")
```

Does anyone have an idea? I tried the basic line:

```
lines(x$DEG[x$Genes == "FEX_0000936"], x$DMG[x$Genes == "FEX_0000936"],
    type="o", pch=22, col="seagreen3")
```

Here is my graph perhaps it is clearer when seeing it:
[image]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You need to give it coordinates in the form (x1,x2),(y1,y2).

Comment: are other packages such as ggplot2 an option for you?

Comment: sure any package :)

Comment: With coordinate it cannot work, I tried segment but the coordinates/scales are different so the dotes on the left is found according to the right scale and it is wrong (Do I make sense?)